# How do I generalize over an Isomorphism?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, isomorphism

So I'm just trying to get a handle on isomorphisms and could use a hand.

I'm writing a text editor and I'd like to think about the cursor's position in two different ways depending on the task, either as a tuple of (row, column) or as a single integer offset into the text object.

I'm building the whole thing using lenses, so this seemed like a good place to learn about Isos.

Originally I had a `Buffer` object:

```
data Buffer = Buffer {
    _text :: T.Text
, _cursor :: Int
} deriving (Show, Eq)
makeLenses ''Buffer
```

But now that the cursor could be a (row, col) tuple I've changed it to:

```
data Buffer c = Buffer {
    _text :: T.Text
, _cursor :: c
} deriving (Show, Eq)
makeLenses ''Buffer
```

Since within the context of a buffer I have an isomorphism from `Buffer Int` to `Buffer (Int, Int)` (this restraint is because I need the text AND the offset in order to do a transformation), I'd love to have all my functions that take a buffer act over either and 'just work'.

Right now I'm stuck on how to make it polymorphic in my definitions,

I can do:

```
appendText :: T.Text -> Buffer c -> Buffer c
```

But then of course I can't actually use the cursor at all because it's completely untyped.

The only roughly related lib I could find was this [type-iso](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-iso-0.1.0.0) library,
and it doesn't look very popular. That, with the notion that I couldn't find any blog posts has me wondering whether this is a thing people do?

If this is a good library to use,
I'm thinking I need to write an instance for [Isomorphic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-iso-0.1.0.0/candidate/docs/Data-Types-Isomorphic.html), and it seems like I get this for free if I write each instance for [Injective](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-iso-0.1.0.0/candidate/docs/Data-Types-Injective.html), but I can't find any docs or examples that I can readily understand so I wanted to check if this is the idiomatic way. If this IS right, do I use the Isomorphic constraint or the Injective one?

**Edit**: I fiddled with it a bit and it seems indeed as though I can implement Injective and get the Iso for free, but again, this lib doesn't seem popular, so I'm looking for the idiomatic approach.

Lastly, for my lens isos do I have to write:

```
toRowColumn :: Iso' (Buffer Offset) (Buffer (Int, Int))
toRowColumn = iso to to

toOffset :: Iso' (Buffer (Int, Int)) (Buffer Offset)
toOffset = iso to to
```

Or is there a better/easier way? Could these be derived from my instances?

Does anyone know of some good lens isomorphism examples or tutorials? Google's not much help :/

Thanks for the help! Just want to check in to make sure I'm doing everything idiomatically.

Comment: I think the most efficient way to do this is actually to at all times keep track of _both_ the row/col pair and absolute offset. Trying to get the one from the other is going to involve traversing the whole text.

Comment: That's likely true, but I'd love to learn how to do this regardless  ;)

Comment: Why don't you just manually define `cursor[From,To]Tup :: Buffer Offset ←→ Buffer (Int, Int)` and use `iso cursorFromTup cursorToTup`? No type classes needed.

Comment: That sounds good, but what do I put as a type restraint on 'c' in the Buffer in the appendText function signature  then?

Comment: @ChrisPenner The point of isomorphisms is not that you remain entirely polymorphic, but that you can easily interconvert between forms. For `appendText` you should choose whichever of the two forms is most convenient. Then, if you need the other form, you can easily convert to it.

Comment: After a bit more looking around it seems that with a similar instance to the `Injective` from that lib I think I can maintain polymorphism with 

`appendText ::  Injective c Offset => T.Text -> Buffer c -> Buffer Offset`

or

`appendText ::  Iso c Offset => T.Text -> Buffer c -> Buffer c` However if you think it's better to just pick one and use the iso lens I suppose that makes sense, I'll just have to convert on the way in with a lens I suppose.

Comment: It seems to me all of these potential solutions are overly complicated.. what is wrong with `cursor :: Either Offset RowCol`? If you want to distinguish between the two on the type level, it isn't much harder: `data CursorType t where Offset :: CursorType Int; RowCol :: CursorType (Int, Int)` and `Buffer :: Text -> c -> CursorType c -> Buffer c`. With such an encoding you can freely write 'parametric' functions which, in fact, can perform case analysis on the type of the cursor.